# Mirroring a number and printing to console

Tags: java, android

I have a number stored in a variable. I need to create a mirror image of this, store in another variable and print it.

I can only find the isMirrored class but that is to check if something is mirror. I need a variable to store the special mirrored character.

Comment: Can you provide an example (input number and output number)?

Comment: Guys i'm not looking to reverse the integer. I need the vertical mirror image of it.

Comment: Is this a joke or serious? How do you think you can take a character, make an image of it, and then store as a newly created character based on an image? Do you think of creating an own font? Or am I missing something? Please clarify in more detail.

Comment: If this is a task that someone has given you, then it may be an attempt to trap you. Or, if it's meant to be serious, then it's definitely something for very very advanced developers.

Answer (score 0):

```java
int n = 123;
System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append(n).reverse());
```

No artificial intelligence  involved ;)

Comment: I actually dont need to reverse the order, i'm talking about the vertical mirror image of the number.